# Parsing "Vale, o valde decóra" in the Ave Regina Caelorum

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, christianity, song-lyrics

> Ave, Regína cælórum,
>   Ave, Dómina Angelórum:
>   Salve radix, salve porta,
>   Ex qua mundo lux est orta:
>   Gaude, Virgo gloriósa,
>   Super omnes speciósa,
>   **Vale, o valde decóra,**
>   Et pro nobis Christum exóra.

I am having trouble deciphering the bolded line of this hymn, especially the word *decora*. Is it an noun, adjective, or verb? The *o* makes me think it is either a noun or an adjective acting as a substantative, but then what is the adverb *valde* doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A valid translation of the relevant piece would be:

> O most (lit. very) beautiful [Lady]!

- [**Decora**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddecorus) is an adjective, feminine in gender (see meaning II for the *beautiful* sense).
- **Valde** is an intensity adverb making **decora** an augmentative (i.e., very beautiful). The relevant part of the definition is: [image]
- Not sure about the punctuation, but the noun is either virgo, or just elided. Anyway the context makes it reasonably obvious who we're talking about

Answer (score 7):

[*Decorus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddecorus) is an adjective that means, in this context, "decorated, ornamented, adorned; elegant, fine, beautiful, handsome." In this case, it is substantivized, "beautiful one."

[*Valde*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=vald%C4%93&la=la&can=vald%C4%930) is the adverb form of *validus* ("strong") and can be used with a verb, adjective, or adverb to intensify it. It's essentially a glorified way of saying "very."

The whole bolded part can thus be translated:

> **Farewell, o most beautiful one.**